# USAMO 2011 Question 2 - Solitaire on a pentagon

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> An integer is assigned to each vertex of a regular pentagon so that
>   the sum of the five integers is 2011. A turn of a solitaire game
>   consists of subtracting an integer $m$ from each of the integers at
>   two neighbouring vertices and adding 2m to the opposite vertex, which
>   is not adjacent to either of the first two vertices. (The amount $m$
>   and the vertices chosen can vary from turn to turn.) The game is won
>   at a certain vertex if, after some number of turns, that vertex has
>   the number 2011 and the other four vertices have the number 0. Prove
>   that for any choice of the initial integers, there is exactly one
>   vertex at which the game can be won.

I have realised that the order of the turns does not matter, however I cannot seem to get any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to deal with the general case for any odd number of vertices and any starting sum (with noted exceptions), because I like giving general solutions :)

Let there be $n$ vertices (where $n$ is odd), labelled $0$ through $n-1$, with vertex $r$ having an associated integer $x_{r}$, and with $\Sigma x = \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}x_{r}$. In your case, $n=5$ and $\Sigma x=2011$.

I also presume that $x_{r}$ can be negative, since the question merely states "integer", and because otherwise there are some states that are unwinnable - for example, in your scenario, any state with one vertex having $2010$ and any other having $1$ is unwinnable if $x_{r}\ge0$ is enforced.

### Method:

1. Find some function $I$ of $\{x_{r}\}$ that is invariant under the allowed transformations of $\{x_{r}\}$. These transformations take the form:
   $$\begin{align}x_{r} &\rightarrow x_{r}-m\\x_{r+1} &\rightarrow x_{r+1}-m\\x_{r+k+1} &\rightarrow x_{r+k+1}+2m\end{align}$$
   where $n=2k+1$ and indices are considered modulo $n$. Try building a quantity that is invariant modulo $n$ - you don't need to get too complicated, a linear combination of $\{x_{r}\}$ will suffice. This invariant will never change throughout the game, so it's a useful quantity to know.
2. Consider the $n$ possible winning states (one for each vertex), and the corresponding values of your invariant - $I_{r}$ being the value of the invariant for the win state where only $x_{r}$ is non-zero. If there are no repeated members in $\{I_{r}\}$, then any initial state can have at most one winning state, since there is at most one winning state you can reach. If $I \notin \{I_{r}\}$, then you cannot win from this state, since you can only reach states that have invariant $I$, and no winning state has invariant $I$. To answer the question, we need $\{I_{r}\}$ to comprise distinct elements, and to contain every possible value of $I$ - hence every state leads to one and only winning state.
3. Now plug in values to solve for the specific case (admittedly, I solved for the specific case first then generalised, you might find it easier to do the process with specific values of $n$ and $\Sigma x$ in mind).

### Answer in spoilers below:

Part 1 (picking an invariant):

> Choose the function $I=(\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}rx_{r})\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n)$, which transforms to $I - rm - (r+1)m + (r+k+1)2m\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n) = I + (2r+2k+2-2r-1)m\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n) = I + (2k+1)m\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n) = I$
> and is hence invariant since it didn't matter what $r$ or $m$ was. It doesn't matter ultimately which vertex is vertex $0$ - while $I$ will depend on the labelling of vertices, it will still indicate the same winning vertex - proof after part 2.

Part 2 (using invariant to deduce possible winning states):

> The function's codomain is the set $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, the integers modulo $n$, and we have $I_{r} = r\Sigma x\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n)$. For any $\Sigma x$ coprime with $n$, $\{I_{r}\}$ will be a set equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$; the winning state is then the $I_{r}$ that equals $I$ - i.e. the winning vertex is $r = I\cdot(\Sigma x)^{-1} \ (\mathrm{mod}\ n)$, where $(\Sigma x)^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $\Sigma x$ modulo $n$ - hence why we require $\Sigma x$ coprime to $n$ as otherwise $(\Sigma x)^{-1}$ does not exist.

Proof why labelling doesn't matter (uses results from parts 1 and 2):

> To prove why the choice of which vertex is vertex $0$ is irrelevant, increment all indices by some amount $a$ (and then reduce modulo $n$). $I$ will then increase by $a\Sigma x\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n)$, thus the winning vertex's index will increase by $a\Sigma x(\Sigma x)^{-1}\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n) = a$, so the winning vertex is the same. As long as you label the vertices consecutively, it doesn't matter which vertex you start from.

Part 3 (solution for specific case):

> Now we have the general solution, in your specific case, all we need show is that $2011$ is coprime with $5$; it clearly is, and in fact $2011 = 1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 5)$, which makes life very easy as its multiplicative inverse is just $1$. Now just compute $I = x_{1}+2x_{2}+3x_{3}+4x_{4}$, and then $I\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 5)$ gives you the winning vertex.